# ionic v4 not worked

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, ionic-framework

I want to make setup and export Android and IOS app LARAVEL package for my CMS!

But every time I get an error message!

[image]
 **program making on ionic 3.4 ~ 3.6!** and i have install:

- android studio 3.1.3
- ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.3.1
- 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- java version "1.8.0_191"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing node_modules and uninstalling ionic:
`npm uninstall ionic` and reinstalling `ionic npm install -g ionic cordova`. Then in your project folder run npm install again.